# Qtp element recognition through diff modules

Tags: vbscript, automation, qtp

Ok this may be a vague question but I have an issue recognizing a webelement in one module (tab) but works completely fine in another tab. This is the same webelement. Everything seems to be same. It's the same form on the gui side with same properties and values.

Now this is another weird part, I can add one to the object repository but when I go to the other tab and try the same qtp becomes extremely slow. The + sign for adding it to the repository appears but when I click it, it gives me a message saying this object cannot be added to the repository.

The Web app uses extJS if that matters and this is a high level webelement that has a constant html id. I'm just puzzled as to why it works in one module but not the other.

There are also some subtabs where you can click on this form. Those work fine but when it comes to capturing this element the issue persists.

Any hypothesis as to why this is happening?

Answer (score 1):

Okay it looks like it works when I took off the visible identification and just identifying it by the html id. I still don't get why taking the visible made a diff but it works.